# How to backup data - PGAdmin4

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

trying to back up my database but I keep getting "'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\pg_dump.exe\pg_dump.exe' file not found. Please correct the Binary Path in the Preferences dialog".
I go ahead to do that and each time the path changes to something new. how do I resolve this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0THM.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PostgreSQL Binary path should be till the bin path. Reason being, there are different binaries for different tasks. Like, pg_dump.exe is used for backup, pg_restore.exe is used for restore and so on. You just have to set the base path.